# Is there css to make my content fit to screen on desktop?

Tags: css

My site is responsive. When I change my window size, the content size scales to fit the window. On mobile it's fine, and on desktop it also scales up and down-according to window size.

My content won't, however, span the whole width of the screen on desktop. Height is fine but width it doesn't stretch right across. It sort of sits between the menu bar and logo.

I tried

```
html, body{height: 100%; width: 100%;}
.container{
width:100%; height: 100%; max-width: 100%; max-height:
100%;position: relative;}
@media screen and (min-width: 48em) 
.blog:not(.has-sidebar) #primary article
{
width: 100%;
}
body:not(.has-sidebar):not(.page-one-column) .page- 
header
{
display: none;
}
.content {position: relative;}

#body {height: 100%; width: 100%;}
```

With

```
.container
```

It did move it, but not across the whole width, just to the left, slightly outside of logo parameter.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

.container{width:100%; height: 100%; max-width: 100%; max-width: 
    100%;**position: relative;**}

the position: relative; take it out :) hope that works.
also 2 max-width's, you can take 1 out as well

---

you can add in your css

```
@media (min-width: 875px) { 
  div#primary {
   margin: 0 auto;
   float: unset;
  }
  #masthead .flex-row 
  { 
    max-width: 66%; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
  }
}
```

Comment: can you link me your website? so i can see it in google chrome?

Comment: Edited question. Just a typo.

Comment: Adsler.co.uk is the site

Comment: if you have <div class="container content"></div> the relative can either come from container or content

Comment: So what do I put?.container doesn't work, so.content?

Comment: i see the <div id="primary"> stays in the left side on desktop you can write in your css, i'll write above

Comment: its not content or container.. the bootstrap has property float: left so all of your content/image etc are floated left.. i edited the top answer  to make it clearer

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks dude

Comment: happy to help, anytime

Comment: Hi, so your code seems to have worked, thanks for that. However, on some desktops, it's pushed my logo and menu bar right to the edges but my content is still in the middle. Is this possible to fix? Ideally I want content to width of logo-menu on mobile, full screen on desktop. Also an option to make all content stretch right to edges, if changes do not look good. Does that make sense? Thanks.

Comment: Also, some background images appear to have been affected. On one, it's only showing half the background image in mobile. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Or even to keep content where it is now, just to move logo and menu bar back into place? Thanks

Comment: added an item above in the main thread a #masthead .flex-row.. to localize the effect in your header. also i dont think that the one you added yesterday affects.. #primary is not in the header its in the content and it wont affect the picture either, because there is no property that overwrites the image related..

Comment: Hi. So put the masthead bit of code in and it distorted my mobile layout. Basically, let me put it like this. The logo and menu are right to the edges of the screen, with a slight border. Is there a way to get the content to the edges of the screen too? Thanks.

Comment: Did it. Just added height: 100%; width 100%; thanks for all your help

Comment: you can filter the css.. with (at symbol)media (min-width: 875px) { (css code here) }  - you can always change the min-width depending on your current screen .. that means the css inside that (at symbol)media affects only until the min-width of 875px.. less than that(mobile mostly are below 675px)

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I managed to do it but the content margin is past the logo. Is there a way to make logo-menu and content align? Like changing margin: 0 auto?

Comment: you can put margin-top: (number)px; in your menu navigation make sure to filiter it or it also affects your mobile..

Comment: anytime mate, i was lucky too when i started this.. someone was there for me.. here in stack overflow :) please give me some arrow up in the main thread :)

Comment: But if i alter div#primary, won't that change the margin of logo and content? How do i alter margin for content and not logo.

Comment: Sure. I voted you but don't have enough points to he recorded.

Comment: its okay :)  no problem

Answer (score 0):

```
div#primary {
margin: 0 auto;
float: unset; height: 100%; width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: please add an explanation to the  code you have provided as to why this is a solution to OP's problem.